# How to convert date format from 05-JUN-99 to 050599?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have gone through the suggested date formats here but didn't find any that meets my requirement.

I have the following date format:

05-JUN-99. 05 being dd as in day, JUN and the year 1999.

I have been asked to convert that to mmddyy (two digit month, two digit day and two digit year).

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Why June month as 05? Is it typo or you are looking some logic?

Comment: Dates do NOT have a format. I suspect you a string that is displaying a date in a certain format. You need to convert your string to a date and then back to a varchar to get the format you want. Be careful though. If you do this with data that can't be cast to a date it will raise an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `convert` here.

```
select convert(varchar(20),cast('05-JUN-99' as date),10)

--Output: 06-05-99

select replace(convert(varchar(20),cast('05-JUN-99' as date),10),'-','')

--Output: 060599
```

[Date Styles from the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: You really should include the length for varchar instead of relying on the default length.

Comment: @SeanLange,

Awesome!

Worked perfectly. Thank you for such a prompt response.

I was going about it the wrong way.

Comment: @SeanLange .. thanks. i modified the query to include length.

Answer (score 2):

My Vote use FORMAT for SQL-SERVER 2012 +

```
SELECT FORMAT(CAST('05-JUN-99' AS DATETIME),'MMddyy')
```

This means no nested replaces, no extraneous cast/converts etc. keeps it tidier IMHO

Comment: I agree this is pretty clean. As long as this isn't using the column from the table this should work fine. The performance of FORMAT is shockingly awful. For one off situations or small datasets it works fine. :)

Comment: @SeanLange yeah I guess I haven't used it in my larger data sets because to me you don't store a date as anything but a date and then you let the GUI do the formatting.  My suspicion on performance would be that it is actually a clr referencing .Nets Format so when applied in a scalar method like this the performance would stink.  so I'll agree on dependent on size of data and performance needs

Comment: Agree 100000% about formatting not belonging in the database at all. I have a feeling a clr procedure would be better for performance than the built in format function but who really knows.

Comment: I suggest you take actual measurements comparing a clr procedure vs a function.

Comment: I like this solution the best for "looks" and ease of understanding.  My solution was more to show the flexibility of what you can do without using the included format functions.  Sometimes you want to format things in ways not covered by these included functions.  Combining strings allow you to do things any way you want with no limitations.

Comment: @SeanLange the format documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx says that it has to be a valid ".Net Framework format string" so I am pretty positive they actually have made FORMAT() a clr to the .Net method. Especially considering scalar clr cross applied against a large rowset has poor performance (reading and my own experience writing clr have shown).  Because for every row it has the overhead of initiating the CLR call.  However if you wrote this as a Table Valued CLR Function well you get that overhead only once and the performance would be dramatically better!

Comment: Have you come across any actual measurements comparing the speed differences between the two methods.

Comment: @MTHead I googled performance and saw a chart https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but   I didn't read in depth but it is inline with cross apply of a scalar clr function. though even with that clr overhead the results shown are worse than I would have expected

Comment: I have yet to find one actual measure that shows clr to be faster than just using the Sql engine.....   This is what I have consistently seen, clr takes more resources.  thanks for the link.

Comment: @MTHead I have definitely seen statistics on CLR Table Valued Functions to be faster than SQL Engine for certain tasks.  The issue is Scalar Valued Functions being applied per row.  There is a lot of overhead to starting up the CLR operation in SQL.  So when per row you incur that overhead per row.  but when table valued you only incur the overhead once.

Comment: I can see that as being possible I just have not seen it in a case for projects I am on.  My thinking if this type of solution was a good idea other sql vendors would copy it or make their version of it.  When I see Microsoft is the only one doing things a certain way I particularly question their solution.  This also does not touch on the potential reliability issues.  Adding more tools makes for more things to go wrong.  Putting more into question the benefit of using what CLR offers that is an improvement.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: @MTHead https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-performance-testing/ shows most of the time clr scalar is slower except when you start doing lots of nested T-SQL functions like a word count.  However CLR Table Valued Functions beach inline t-SQL most of the time in the article

Comment: @Matt, interesting, that sounds sensible.  I would bet this is only true on larger data sets.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just convert to string.  Get the year, month, day, put them each in a string and concatinate them.

```
Declare @InputValue Varchar(16) = '05-JUN-99'
set @InputValue = replace(@InputValue,'-','/')
declare @TestDate DateTime
set @TestDate = convert(DateTime,@InputValue) 
select @TestDate
select   right ('0' + convert(Varchar(2),DATEPART(mm,@TestDate)),2) 
       + right ('0' + convert(Varchar(2),DATEPART(dd,@TestDate)),2)
       + right ('0' + convert(Varchar(4),DATEPART(yy,@TestDate)),2)
```

Comment: Your input is not what the OP stated they have and this just isn't going to work with their input.

Comment: @Sean are you saying I had my month and day swapped around?

Comment: No. They clearly stated the input string is "05-JUN-99". You have to change JUN to 06. The easiest way to do that is with a date(time) dataype.

Comment: It says they have a "date" not input string.

Comment: Actually they say they have a date with this format...that almost always is an indication they have a varchar with data that looks like a date. Nonetheless this will work.

Comment: @sean let me know if the latest modification covers what you were saying.

Comment: It absolutely does. I had misread your original post the first time. I don't think you need the replace to switch - for / but it doesn't make any difference. This does work.

Comment: The swapping of a - for a / is needed depending on which Sql server version you are on.